# Can I indent the details tag information that shows beneath a summary tag display?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to indent the details information as it shows under the summary tag?
Currently the information is left-aligned with both tags.

```
    <details> Details 1
     <summary> Summary 1 </summary> 
    </details>
    
    <details>
     <summary> Summary 2 </summary> 
     Details 2
    </details>
    
    <details> Details 3
     <summary> Summary 3 </summary> 
    </details>
```

I have tried text-indent, but it indents the summary information and NOT the details.

Comment: notes that negative text-indent and padding might work together : https://jsfiddle.net/naLxk6wo/  `details {
  padding-inline-start:2rem;
}
details summary {
  text-indent:-2rem;
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative margin seems to work pretty well.

```css
details {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

summary {
  margin-left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<details> Details 1
 <summary> Summary 1 </summary> 
</details>

<details>
 <summary> Summary 2 </summary> 
 Details 2
</details>

<details> Details 3
 <summary> Summary 3 </summary> 
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Seems pretty simple once you know it :)

Answer (score 1):

With margin or padding you can style it. Example with padding:

```css
details > summary {
  background-color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

details > summary > * {
  display: inline;
}

details > div {
  border: 2px solid #888;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 35px;
}
```

```html
  <details> 
    <div>Details  1 </div>
     <summary> Summary 1 </summary> 
  </details>
    
    <details>      
     <summary> Summary 2 </summary> 
     <div>Details  2 </div>
    </details>
    
    <details> 
     <summary> Summary 3 </summary> 
      <div>Details  3 </div>
    </details>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like I have the option to become more elaborate if needed :)